# Xamarin : An element with the key 'X' already exists in NameScope

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the following error when I try to push to a new page.

(I'm using Xamarin.Form 4.6.0.800)

```
{System.ArgumentException: An element with the key 'NewAccountLogo' already exists in NameScope
Parameter name: name
  at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NameScope.Xamarin.Forms.Internals.INameScope.RegisterName (System.String name, System.Object scopedElement) [0x0000e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\NameScope.cs:21 
  at amici.NewAccount.InitializeComponent () [0x00078] in C:\Users\X\source\repos\amici\amici\amici\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\NewAccount.xaml.g.cs:46 
  at amici.NewAccount..ctor () [0x0000f] in C:\Users\X\source\repos\amici\amici\amici\NewAccount.xaml.cs:26 
  at amici.Logon+<OnCreateAccountClick>d__3.MoveNext () [0x0002a] in C:\Users\X\source\repos\amici\amici\amici\logon.xaml.cs:119 }
```

The error seems straight forward so I went back and renamed the element and then searched my project for the same name. (there is only one). Recompiled and tried it again, same message but with the new name? so I delete the element and tried recompiled and tried it again, interesting enough I get the same message but with the next element? So now I’m thinking maybe the error message is not quite right or is trying to tell me something else. I just can’t figure it out. Below is my xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             Title="New Account"
             x:Class="amici.NewAccount">
    <ContentPage.Content >
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid>
                <StackLayout Margin="20" Padding="10" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                    <Image x:Name="NewAccountLogo"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="NewEmail" Placeholder="Email"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="EmailConfirm" Placeholder="Confirm Email"/>

                    <Label Text="Password between 6 and 20 characters; must contain at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one numeric digit." Margin="0,0,0,5"></Label>


                    <Entry x:Name="NewPassword" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="PasswordConfirm" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Confirm Password"/>

                    <Label x:Name="bntCreatAccountButton" TextColor="Blue" Text="Create Account" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,25,0,0">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnCreateAccount" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="WaitIcon"  IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

code behind :

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewAccount : ContentPage
    {
        public NewAccount()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
            this.IsBusy = false;

            var bkgrndGradient = new Gradient()
            {
                Rotation = 150,
                Steps = new GradientStepCollection()
                {
                    new GradientStep(Color.White, 0),
                    new GradientStep(Color.White, .5),
                    new GradientStep(Color.FromHex("#ccd9ff"), 1)
                }
            };

            ContentPageGloss.SetBackgroundGradient(this, bkgrndGradient);
            NewAccountLogo.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("logo.png");
        }



        async private void OnCreateAccount(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string Message = string.Empty;
            string title = string.Empty;
            bool results = false;
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {


                if (ComparisonBehavior.CompareValues(NewEmail.Text, NewPassword.Text, EmailConfirm.Text,PasswordConfirm.Text, ref Message, ref title))
                {

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    results = RestController.CreateAccount(NewEmail.Text, NewPassword.Text);
                    IsBusy = false;

                    if (results)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("New Account Created.", "Thank You! Please check your email (junk mail) to activate your subscription.", "OK");
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();

                    }else
                    {
                        if (Application.Current.Properties["resp"].ToString() == "Account exist")
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Account Exist", "Sorry this email already exist!", "OK");
                        }

                    }
                }else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert(title, Message, "OK");
                }


            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 await DisplayAlert("internal Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            } finally{
                IsBusy = false;
           }

        }
    }
```

any help would be appreciated.
Mike

Comment: do you have a variable declared in your code behind with a conflicting name?

Comment: #Jason, no I don't think so, I have added the code behind to the question

Comment: @Jason, Like I state in my question if I delete the conflicting element it just goes to the next name in the XAML.

Comment: you can follow through below bugs https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9366 https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8675

Comment: @ Karan Rami  check it out and it didn't hep me solve my issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my Code behind I had  **InitializeComponent ();** declared twice.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too got the same exception and when i checked the code behind my bad, there are two InitializeComponent(); in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue generally happens when the system tries to Initialize the same components with the same name. Please check `InitializeComponent();` maybe, it has declared twice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to bind a component to its' code behind class instead of its' view model. I was doing:

```
<Picker
    BindingContext={x:Reference x:Name=ThisPage} 
/>
```

The problem was that `x:Name=ThisPage` was actually trying to set a new name for X Namespace instead of referencing one, when I changed it to `Name=ThisPage` it worked fine.